# Why when adding the qualifier const in a pointer declaration with a type-alias makes a const pointer rather than pointer to const?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
const char numm = 11;   
typedef char* pstring;
const pstring cstr = &numm; //Error
```

I learned this from C++ Primer, but it didn't quite clarify it for me. Here is a code example.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ptr-vs-ptr-const

Comment: The `const` is applied to the type.  You are applying it to the `pstring`, which is the same as if you had done:  `char * const cstr = &numm;` ... and that's not what you wanted, you wanted `char const * cstr = &numm;`

Comment: Try reading your code aloud (to force you to hear what you wrote instead of what you meant to write)? You've declared `cstr` to be a `const pstring`, a `pstring` that cannot be changed. What is a `pstring`? It's a `char*`. So the type of `cstr` is a pointer that cannot be changed.

Comment: `pstring` is a `char*`. If you now declare a `const pstring` you get a constant (char **pointer**). I added the braces to indicate the "ordering" of "operation".  On the other hand, `const char *` is declaring a pointer to a constant char.

Comment: The main missunderstanding here is that `typedef` is not simply text substitution.

Comment: The target is for C, but the described behavior in the target question is the same for both languages, and the answer applies to both languages as well.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann So in basic terms of speaking, declaring a const pstring I'm basically saying make char * const right?

Comment: @Gamerguy123lo exactly